# How to pass a cookie through a socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, cookies

I looked for a while now but I didn't found a good guide about passing a cookie to a socketserver.

I know I can store cookies with the HttpClient library, but how can I send the stored cookie to a socket after connecting to the socket?

Answer (score 2):

**Cookies** don't live at the **socket layer level**, they live in the **HTTP layer**, so you can't use them with your low level socket.

So you'll have either to implement your own cookies like system at the **TCP level** or work at the higher **HTTP level**.

EDIT:

If you want to forge the request yourself you can try something like:

```
GET /authenticatedPage.html HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.thesite.com\r\n
Cookie: SESSID=123456abc789\r\n
\r\n
```

To test your request without running your program you can use a **Telnet** client.

Comment: I have to connect to an Socket and send him the SESSID from the cookie in a header

Comment: Can't you connect using an Http client like the Apache HttpClient you mention? If no then you'll have to forge HTTP requests and this is not trivial, I'll update my answer with a sample.

Comment: No I can login to the site via httpclient to get the cookie, but then I have to connect to a socket, which is a chatserver. I will try your smaple, thanks!